# Python Twisted WebSocket client

Tags: python, websocket, twisted

Having worked with Twisted in the past I'd like to know if there is a way to get WebSocket client support to work. Looking around the documentation I can only find server implementations.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Tavendo Autobahn](http://www.tavendo.de/autobahn/) is a very featureful websockets implementation.  One of those features is [a Python WebSockets client with Twisted support](http://www.tavendo.de/autobahn/python_features.html).

Comment: are you involved/supporting Autobahn? If so, has to say something that a Twisted core dev is recommending it.  Also I believe the URL has changed for your answer to http://autobahn.ws/python/

Comment: Indeed, it would be nice to know if this is the official recommendation or not. Twisted has a websocket server, why not a client? Unfortunately I know a couple of Twisted programs that use Tornado to do the websocket client and that feel *really* ugly...